# Correct syntax with IN condition on a find() query in mongolite

Tags: r, mongolite

I am trying to use an IN condition to query with the mongolite package. I can get the query to work if I use the mongo console based on this page:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in. I've tried variations on the following in my R code, but either end up with 0 results or a syntax error:

```
aaContDF <- mongoBirdData$find('{ "aircraftAirlineOperator": { "$in":
                               { [ "AMERICAN AIRLINES",
                               "CONTINENTAL AIRLINES" ] } } }',
                               fields = '{"recordId":1, "originState":1,
                               "aircraftAirlineOperator":1,
                               "airportName":1}')
```

With error message:

```
Error: Invalid JSON object: { "aircraftAirlineOperator": { "$in":
                           { [ "AMERICAN AIRLINES",
                           "CONTINENTAL AIRLINES" ] } } }
```

The queries I've worked with have been AND conditions, haven't encountered any OR scenarios yet.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by being more patient and adding pieces step-by-step:

```
aaContDF <- mongoBirdData$find('{ "aircraftAirlineOperator" : 
                           { "$in" : [ "AMERICAN AIRLINES",
                           "CONTINENTAL AIRLINES"]  } }',
                           fields = '{"recordId":1, "originState":1,
                           "aircraftAirlineOperator":1,
                           "airportName":1,
                           "_id":0}')
```